# Typing: Inferred type too general during class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I'm facing the following problem. Suppose I want to define generic class for `Dataset` and its `Sample`s. Then, I want to create specific subclasses of these that will in the end be instantiated (E.g. `DatasetOfSpecificSamples` that contains `MoreSpecificSample` samples). To save some LoC, I want to implement common functionality in `Dataset` class.

Yet, I can't get the typehints in the inherited sublcasses right. They are too general. See the following example, where I would expect that `__iter__` return type of `DatasetOfSpecificSamples` would be `MoreSpecificSample`, yet MyPy infers just `Sample`.

Is there a way to enforce *more specific* hint without redifining the method itself?

```py
from typing import Mapping, Iterator

class Sample:
    pass


class MoreSpecificSample(Sample):
    pass


class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, samples: Mapping[str, Sample]):
        self.samples = samples

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Sample]:
        yield from self.samples.values()


class DatasetOfSpecificSamples(Dataset):
    samples: Mapping[str, MoreSpecificSample]

    # def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[CommonCriteriaCert]: <-- This fixes the problem, as it specifies the type
    #     yield from self.certs.values()

dset = DatasetOfSpecificSamples()
for sample in dset: # <-- the inferred type of "sample" is Sample, not MoreSpecificSample
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Dataset` class Generic:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

class Dataset(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, samples: Mapping[str, T]):
        self.samples = samples

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        yield from self.samples.values()


class DatasetOfSpecificSamples(Dataset[MoreSpecificSample]):
    samples: Mapping[str, MoreSpecificSample]
```

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks a lot! I was not aware how to use Generic type. I'm having problems finding any well-written material on the typing module (PEP seems too cryptic at places). I wanted to extend your solution with saying that redefining the variable `samples` is no longer neccessary in the child classes. Also, for my use case it's probably wise to bound the typevar to `Typevar("T", bound=Sample)`, as I'm not allowing any other classes in the `Dataset`.

Comment: The mypy doc are good: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/